# Running all tests in the same browser webdriver testng

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I currently have my tests set up that each class instantiates its own browser. Each class is based on a page I want to test. I now want my tests to all to run in the one browser. Mu code has the current set up. I have a base page where common methods are inherited, I then have a java.class for the methods of a specific page followed by a test.class to run my tests from.

```
public class BasePage {

@FindBy(id = "j_username") WebElement field_Username;
@FindBy(id = "j_password") WebElement field_Password;
@FindBy(name = "login") WebElement button_Login;

public WebDriver driver;
public WebDriverWait wait;

protected JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor;

public String PAGE_URL;
public String PAGE_TITLE;

public BasePage(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
    jsExecutor = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 200);
}

public void loadPage(){

    driver.get(getPageUrl());
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){ 
        driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SUBTRACT));
        } 
}

protected void login(String username, String password){
    findDynamicElement(By.id("j_username") , 7);
    setText_Login(username);
    setText_PasswordLogin(password);
    clickLoginMain();
}

public class CreateBillingRange  extends BasePage {

    @FindBy(id = "j_username") WebElement field_Username;
    @FindBy(id = "j_password") WebElement field_Password;
    @FindBy(name = "login") WebElement button_Login;
    @FindBy(id = "add_label") WebElement button_AddLabel;
    @FindBy(linkText = "Policy") WebElement field_Policy;
    @FindBy(linkText = "SPCM") WebElement field_SPCM;
    @FindBy(linkText = "Billing Range") WebElement field_BR;
    @FindBy(id = "addChargingProfile_label") WebElement button_addChargingProfile;
    @FindBy(name = "addBillingNumberRange") WebElement button_addBillingNumberRange;
    @FindBy(id = "startRange") WebElement field_StartRange; 
    @FindBy(id = "endRange") WebElement field_EndRange; 
    @FindBy(id = "name") WebElement field_Name;
    @FindBy(name = "saveBillingNumberRange") WebElement button_SaveBillingNumberRange;

    @FindBy(id = "number") WebElement field_NumberSearch;
    @FindBy(name = "search") WebElement field_Submit;
    @FindBy(name = "ids") WebElement checkbox_Number;
    @FindBy(name = "deleteBillingNumberRange") WebElement button_Delete;
    @FindBy(id = "okDialogButton_label") WebElement okDialogButton_label;



    public CreateBillingRange(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        this.PAGE_URL = "http://xxxxx:xxx/page";
    }

    public void login(String username, String password){
        findDynamicElement(By.id("j_username") , 7);
        setText_Login(username);
        setText_PasswordLogin(password);
        clickLoginMain();
    }

    public void setText_Login(String text){
        setElementText(field_Username, text);
    }


    public void setText_PasswordLogin(String text){
        setElementText(field_Password, text);
    }

    public void clickLoginMain(){
        clickElement(button_Login);
    }

    public void click_SignUpButton(){
        clickElement(button_Login);
    }

    public void openCharging() {

        findDynamicElement(By.linkText("Policy") , 19);
        clickElement(field_Policy);
        clickElement(field_SPCM);
        clickElement(field_BR);

    }   

    public void addBillingRange(String start, String end){
        findDynamicElement(By.name("addBillingNumberRange"), 10);
        clickElement(button_addBillingNumberRange);
        findDynamicElement(By.id("startRange"), 3);
        setElementText(field_StartRange, start);
        setElementText(field_EndRange, end);
        clickElement(button_SaveBillingNumberRange);
        findDynamicElement(By.id("successMessages") , 5);
    }

    public void deleteBillingRange(String BillingRange){
        findDynamicElement(By.name("search"),20);
        field_NumberSearch.click();
        field_NumberSearch.sendKeys(BillingRange);
        field_Submit.click();
        findDynamicElement(By.name("ids"),20);
        checkbox_Number.click();
        button_Delete.click();
        accpetConfirmSuccess();

    }




public class CreateBundle  extends BasePage{

    @FindBy(id = "j_username") WebElement field_Username;
    @FindBy(id = "j_password") WebElement field_Password;
    @FindBy(name = "login") WebElement button_Login;
    @FindBy(id = "add_label") WebElement button_AddLabel;
    @FindBy(linkText = "Policy") WebElement field_Policy;
    @FindBy(linkText = "SPCM") WebElement field_SPCM;
    @FindBy(linkText = "Plan Mgmt") WebElement field_PlanMgmt;
    @FindBy(linkText = "Bundles") WebElement field_Bundles;
    @FindBy(id = "addOcsButton_label") WebElement button_addOCS;
    @FindBy(id = "alias") WebElement field_alias;
    @FindBy(id = "value") WebElement field_value;
    @FindBy(id = "submitActionButton_label") WebElement button_OCSsave; 
    @FindBy(id = "add") WebElement button_addLabel;
    @FindBy(id = "dataPlanName") WebElement field_DataPlan;
    @FindBy(id = "addComboPackServiceButton_label") WebElement button_addComboService;
    @FindBy(id = "amount") WebElement field_amount;
    @FindBy(id = "ocsAccountReference") WebElement field_OCSAccount;
    @FindBy(id = "days") WebElement field_Days;
    @FindBy(id = "submitActionButton_label") WebElement button_SubmitAction;
    @FindBy(id = "save_label") WebElement button_BundleSave;

    @FindBy(id = "dataPlanName") WebElement field_OCSSearch;
    @FindBy(id = "search_label") WebElement field_OCSSubmit;
    @FindBy(name = "ids") WebElement checkbox_OCS;
    @FindBy(id = "delete_label") WebElement button_DeleteOCS;
    @FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/fieldset[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/input") WebElement field_OCSDelete;
    @FindBy(id = "deleteOcsRef_label") WebElement button_deleteOCS;


    public CreateBundle(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        this.PAGE_URL = "http://xxxxx.xxx.x/page";
    }


    public void openBundle() {

        findDynamicElement(By.linkText("Policy") , 19);
        clickElement(field_Policy);
        clickElement(field_SPCM);
        clickElement(field_PlanMgmt);
        clickElement(field_Bundles);

    }   

public class BillingRange_Test {


    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;
    CreateBillingRange CreateBillingRange;


    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException{
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
        this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.237:5556/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        CreateBillingRange = PageFactory.initElements(driver, CreateBillingRange.class );
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void teardown(){
        this.driver.quit();
    }


    @BeforeTest
    public void testSignUpMainPage(){
        CreateBillingRange.loadPage();
        CreateBillingRange.login("super","5tg7uj6yh");

    }

    @Test(priority=1,retryAnalyzer=Retry.class)
    public void addBillingRange(){
        CreateBillingRange.openCharging();
        CreateBillingRange.addBillingRange("8800088","1111111111");

    }


public class Bundle_Test {


    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;
    CreateBundle CreateBundle;


    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException{
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
        this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.237:5556/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        CreateBundle = PageFactory.initElements(driver, CreateBundle.class );
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void teardown(){
        this.driver.quit();
    }


    @Test(priority=1)
    public void testSignUpMainPage(){
        CreateBundle.loadPage();
        CreateBundle.login("super","5tg7uj6yh");

    }

    @Test(retryAnalyzer=Retry.class)
    public void addBundle(){
        CreateBundle.openBundle();
        CreateBundle.createBundles("Accum 4Mins 4MB", "1","SMS","1");

    }
```

How do I run my tests in the one browser??

Answer (score 0):

There is one way i am aware of, but that can should implicate in some problems if you decide to run the same test in parallel. I'd advise you study a little bit about static parameters to see if it suits you.

When you start your first test do it as follows:

```
public class Driver()
{
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
    public static driver = new Webdriver(new URL("192.168.1.237:5556/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}
public class Tests()
{
    public void Test1(Webdriver driver)
    {
        driver.Navigate(pageurl);
        driver.Findelement();
        //etc
     }
}
//Implementation like
Test1(Driver.driver);
```

That way any test that you call driver.someFunction(); will work, as long as you don't call for close() or quit() until you reach the last test.

Comment: Where should I set my static Webdriver to static? I'm a little confused how to where to use it?

Comment: Just implement one static instance of webdriver and implement that same instance in all your tests.

Comment: Do I implement it in the base page?

Comment: You could. And then in your other classes and method you could add it as a parameter and pass that instance in. See how you create another instance of webdriver in each of your test classes?

Comment: driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.237:5556/wd/hub"), capabilities);   make this static and just refer to class.driver everywhere else

Comment: Check the code I just put up. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: If I change for example Bundle_Test to static  WebDriver driver;                   driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("192.168.1.237:5556/wd/hub"), capabilities);  how can I refer to the class if the pages are separate objects?

Comment: Just have the driver navigate to the URL you want at the beginning of your test via Navigate.

Comment: CreateBillingRange = PageFactory.initElements(Driver.driver, CreateBillingRange.class );

Comment: I wouldn't have the webdriver in one of your tests. Create a new class and then you have your webdriver object. You can then pass different page objects to that instance of webdriver.

Comment: I s till can't get it to work. Could you use my code as an example or point me to some articles?